# RAILS-JQUERY: PASS DATA FROM VIEW1 TO ANOTHER VIEW2

Tags: jquery, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

I am learning jquery. I would do something like this: in view1 I have an select_tag with its options (1, 2, 3...). I select one option  and pass it to view2. In view2, I also have an select_tag witn its options but can be do multiple select. Sum of the selected options must be equal to number that I sent. After submit or refresh/reload page, I would keep checked the selected options in view2. Please can you help me? Thank you very much!

View1

```
<%= form_tag(view2_path, method: "get") do %>
 <%= select_tag "num", "<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option>".html_safe, :id => "sel"%>
<%= submit_tag "Ok"%>
<% end %>
```

View2

```
 <%= form_tag(another_path, method: "get", id: "sel") do %>
   <table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Numero</th>

  </tr>
<% for posti in @postis %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "posti_ids[]", posti.id %></td>
    <td><%=h posti.numero %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
    <%= submit_tag "Ok", id: "sub"%>
    <% end %>
```

View1.js: There is no problem here.

```
$(document).ready(function($)
{
   $('#sel').change(function() {
    var mylist = document.getElementById("sel");
    iterations = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
    window.localStorage.setItem("num",iterations);

    alert(window.localStorage.getItem("num"));
    window.location.assign(scegli_posti_path);

});
});
```

View2.js: I have some problems here
problem1: how can i retrieve data on select_tag?
problem2: sum of checked element must be equals to data i pass. How can i do it?
problem3: How can i keep checked options that i check after reload/return on View2?

```
   $(document).ready(function() {  


    var c= window.localStorage.getItem("num");
    var a=0;

 $("#sel").click( function(){
        var chkId= [];

        $("#posti_ids_:checked").each(function() {
          chkId.push( $(this).val());

          a=chkId.length;
        });



      });
 $("#sub").click( function(){

        if(a != c)
        {
                    alert("Sum of checkboxes selected must equal at number that you pass");
                    return false;

        }
 });

});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi... Looks like you are new and need help.  The best thing to do is to construct some HTML and your best guess at how you would write your jQuery (look for examples).  Then come back and post your code.  That way we can see what you are doing 'in code' and provide solutions.

Comment: Thank you, i will post my jquery code

Comment: Hi, very good on getting more details in the question.  This has fallen out of that immediate time span sweet spot for stack overflow, but there are no answers to your post yet so maybe others will pick it up when they 'filter by unanswered'. I am not a Ruby programmer so hopefully someone can chime in there. I will look this over tomorrow and so if anything jumps out at me on the jQuery stuff.  I'll let you know either way.

Comment: Ok Frank thank you. I wait some answers from every body

Comment: Hi Franck i edited my post. Code works very well. Now i want to keep checkbox checked after submit an refresh/reload the view2. How can i do? THANKS